# What is the design reason behind these components?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, capacitor, circuit-design

I have some questions regarding the comparison of these two circuits. Both produce current noise through the first reverse-biased transistor. That variable current enters through the base of the second transistor, affecting its collector's voltage.

What is the purpose of the components R1, R2, and C2 connected to the bases in the second schematic?  How do they affect the noise production? What differs from the first schematic and why are the 1MR values for the resistors?

Why is the 680KR resistor in the emitter of the first transistor in the first schematic and not on the second one? It might be related to the first question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Second circuit has much higher gain and uses self-biasing to make the most out of the available supply voltage range

Comment: @tobalt would you mind explaining further in an answer? I'm a beginner and I'm trying to understand the implications and differences both on an analytic and intuitive level. I'll mark it as corrected answer of course

Comment: First C1 blocks the DC component so that whatever voltage is used to make the noise in Q1 doesn't have to be the same voltage that amplifies it in Q2. Then R1 is used to allow current through Q1 to make the noise, and R2 is used to get a good voltage for Q2 to amplify it. By contrast, the first schematic forces them to use the same voltage for both purposes. The DC voltage/current that flows through a transistor that has nothing to do with the signal being amplified is called "bias"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's instructive to look at this circuit separately in terms of DC and AC. The DC signal is related to the biasing of each stage and is blocked by the series capacitors, while the AC signal flows through the capacitors from stage to stage, and is the signal being amplified. I'll walk through the circuit from left to right, discussing the DC and AC at each stage.

C1 provides AC coupling, meaning that the DC values of Q1 base and Q2 base can be different. R1 then provides a path to ground, reverse-biasing the Q1 base-emitter junction which causes it to produce AC flicker noise ([ref](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee142_f10/Lectures/lecture14_AA.pdf)).

Looking at C1 analytically, it produces a high-pass filter. Frequencies below  a certain cutoff are not allowed through it; I'd estimate the cutoff on the order of 10-100 Hz, since the time constant is RC, where C is 100 nF and R is the effective impedance of Q1's junction, R1, and the input impedance of the amplifier based on Q2. I'd estimate this effective impedance to be on the order of 100k ish ohms, with 1 MOhm as an upper bound (because of R1). Note that this is a highly approximated and handwaved argument, and hand calculation or simulation will be required to get a more precise value.

R2 provides self-biasing as a form of feedback for the [common-emitter amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter) based around Q2. When the output at the collector of Q2 rises, it increases the voltage on the base of Q2, which increases the current through Q2 and provides negative feedback by reducing the collector voltage of Q2 thanks to that higher current pulling the collector voltage down.

Because of C1, the DC voltage at the base of Q2 doesn't have to match the DC voltage at the base of Q1. This lets Q2 settle into a good operating point as a consequence of its own transfer characteristic (in purple) and the resistor feedback (in green). Note the slope of the transfer characteristic is very high - a small change in base voltage will produce a large change in collector voltage, meaning the gain is high, while the operating point is away from amplifier saturation (marked as 'Poor gain'):

[image]

The AC noise signal from Q1 enters the amplifier, and gets amplified by this high gain, producing a stronger AC signal at the collector.

Finally, C2 provides an additional level of AC coupling, keeping the DC bias of Q2's collector out of the output signal.

Compare this to the first circuit - the same DC bias is used for the base of Q1 and Q2; this bias is a consequence of base current in Q2 and reverse leakage in Q1, and chances are it could be a lousy bias for optimal performance of Q1, Q2, or both.